# why custom allocator for std::string does not work

Tags: c++, string, allocator

I define a new allocator like this:

```
template <class T>
class CodecAlloc: public std::allocator<T> {
public:
  typedef size_t    size_type;
  typedef ptrdiff_t difference_type;
  typedef T*        pointer;
  typedef const T*  const_pointer;
  typedef T&        reference;
  typedef const T&  const_reference;
  typedef T         value_type;

  CodecAlloc() {}
  CodecAlloc(const CodecAlloc&) {}

  pointer allocate(size_type n, const void * = 0) {
              T* t = (T*) malloc(n * sizeof(T));
              std::cout
              << "  used CodecAlloc to allocate   at address "
              << t << " (+)" << std::endl;
              return t;
            }

  void deallocate(void* p, size_type) {
              if (p) {
                free(p);
                std::cout
                << "  used CodecAlloc to deallocate at address "
                << p << " (-)" << 
                std::endl;
              } 
            }

  template <class U>
  struct rebind { typedef CodecAlloc<U> other; };
};
```

if I typedef a new type:

```
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, CodecAlloc<char>> String;
```

it work well，CodecAlloc::allocate has been called.  but now there is a interface like this:

```
void SetBinary(const std::string&)
```

it's parameter is a std::string, the type `String` does not match. So I use this way to construct `std::string`

```
std::string str = std::string("Hello !!", CodecAlloc<char>);
SetBinary(str)
```

but the CodecAlloc allocator does not been called!! why? and how should i solve this problem. the SetBinary interface can not be changed. thks

Comment: Do you get any kind of error ? if you do please include it.

Comment: Small string optimisation? Can you try a longer (32+ chars) string?

Comment: Think about it: how would `std::string` know about your `deallocate` when it comes to deallocation? `std::string` allocator is not type-erased one. With your allocator as a template parameter, you get a distinct type, unrelated to `std::string`.

Comment: @dt170, there is not.  but CodecAlloc::allocate is not be called.

Comment: @dt170 is seems very unlikely that there is no error - either the code is not compiled or smth else happens, but `std::string` just does not have a constructor that could match the given args.

Answer (score 2):

So, the line

```
std::string str = std::string("Hello !!", CodecAlloc<char>);
```

is just wrong and has several errors:

1. You can't use `CodecAlloc<char>` since that is a type. You need to pass an allocator instance, so at least `CodecAlloc<char>()` is needed.
2. If 1. is fixed, it will still not work since the passed allocator differs from the one used by `std::string`. You could fix it to use your type `String`:
   `std::string str = String("Hello !!", CodecAlloc<char>);`, but that won't work, since `std::string` does not have an assigment operator from a type with a different allocator - see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D)

So with the detailed explanation above the answer is - no you cannot achieve what you want and pass a custom typedef'ed `std::basic_string` in a `std::string` and preserve your custom allocator.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string str = std::string("Hello !!", CodecAlloc<char>);
```

Assuming that you actually created a temporary like `CodecAlloc<char>()` (because otherwise it wouldn't compile) what happens is that you call the constructor taking a `const std::allocator<char>&` (because that's what `std::string::allocator_type` is) and your object has that as a base class. So the reference binds to the base subobject of your `CodecAlloc<char>` temporary, and then that base subobject gets copied into the string's internal allocator object.

You can't make `std::string` use a different allocator type just by passing it to the constructor, the allocator type is a static property of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I have bad news for you.

The other answers already covered this nicely, but I wanted to be more explicit about this: **you will not be able to use this interface with a string that uses a custom allocator**. Or with any other kind of string, for that matter.

To understand why, you need to know what `std::string` is. If you look for "string" on cppreference, you'll be directed to the page for [`std::basic_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). This is intentional, `std::basic_string` is a template that defines a collection of string classes, and `std::string` is one of them.

If you look at the definition of `std::string`, you'll see that it is defined as `std::basic_string<char>`, which is a shortcut for `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>`. This means that `std::string` **already comes embedded with its own allocator**, which is not extensible: the member functions `std::allocator<T>::allocate` and `std::allocator<T>::deallocate` are not virtual. Assuming you wanted to use this constructor from `std::basic_string`:

```
basic_string( const CharT* s, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

... that means that even if the constructor is using a reference to the allocator, these functions (`allocate` and `deallocate`) will not be overridden: the constructor doesn't even know about your version of them. Instead, it will use the versions from the base class.